# Gaussian binomial coeffcient

Tags: combinatorics

Let the Gaussian Binomial Coefficient be defined for a prime $q$ as

\begin{equation}\binom{N}{l}_{q}:=\prod_{i=0}^{l-1} \frac{q^{N-i}-1}{q^{l-i}-1}\end{equation}

Now I want to show that, for $D>2$:

\begin{equation} \binom{N-(D-2)/2}{N-l}_{q}<\binom{N-(D-2)/2}{l}_{q}  \end{equation}

if and only if $l<N-l$. Does anyone know how to do this? I've tried with a few examples and I can see that these are true. But I'm not sure how to prove it in general? Any hints?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is there any restriction on $q$, say $0<q<1$?

Comment: Should have mentioned that. $q$ is a prime such that $\mathbb{F}_q$ is field.

Comment: I think this is not true. for D=2, by the symmetry of the Gaussian binomial coefficients, you always have equality.

Comment: That is true but I'm mostly interested in the case where $D>2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true; here's a sketch. Let $c=(D-2)/2$. $\binom{N-c}{l}_q$ is unimodal and symmetric in $l$, so your inequality will hold precisely when $l$ is closer to $(N-c)/2$ than $N-l$ is. With a little algebra you can see that this is equivalent to saying $N-2l$ is closer to $c$ than to $-c$. Since $c>0$ this is equivalent to $N-2l >0$ and you're done.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you! One question though; how do you prove that $\binom{N-c}{l}_q$ is unimodal?

Comment: It's a standard fact, but not hard to see.  The ratio $\binom{m}{l+1}_q / \binom{m}{l}_q$ is $(m-l)_q/(l+1)_q$, where $(m)_q=1+q+q^2+\cdots+q^{m-1}$.  This ratio is at least one if $m-l \ge l+1$, i.e. $l\le (m-1)/2$.  So, for fixed $m$, $\binom ml$ increases for $l\le (m-1)/2$, is constant for one step if $m$ is odd, and then decreases (by symmetry).